# Clean up AWS Instances - VPCs and Internet Gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I tried to set up (several times) Jenkins X on EKS by using
`jx create cluster eks` command. I hit many errors while doing this, but kept trying and started the command several times. My last run resolved in:

```
2021-03-06 08:10:56 [✖]  AWS::IAM::Role/ServiceRole: CREATE_FAILED – "Resource creation cancelled"
2021-03-06 08:10:56 [✖]  AWS::EC2::EIP/NATIP: CREATE_FAILED – "Resource creation cancelled"
2021-03-06 08:10:56 [✖]  AWS::EC2::InternetGateway/InternetGateway: CREATE_FAILED – "The maximum number of internet gateways has been reached. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InternetGatewayLimitExceeded; Request ID: 1e661306-cf44-42da-8456-636eee94ab60; Proxy: null)"
2021-03-06 08:10:56 [✖]  AWS::EC2::VPC/VPC: CREATE_FAILED – "The maximum number of VPCs has been reached. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: VpcLimitExceeded; Request ID: 78098dfb-111a-4f9c-98b4-48ececac6249; Proxy: null)"
```

ok... time to clean up

I went to ClaudFormation and tried to delete all stacks. Nodes were wiped out but clusters can't be deleted due to dependencies
[image: CloudFormation stacks]

Expanding one of the failed deletes shows me this:
[image]

Trying to delete a stack again:
[image]

Click on the InternetGateway from the list and try to detach it. I get following error:
[image]

Going to VPC Console to unmap the public addresses I see I don't have any NAT Gateways or Virtual Private Gateways
[image]

My questions are: Where do I start? How to delete all those resources from AWS?

Comment: Check your Elastic IPs. Screenshot shows 1.

Comment: @Marcin should I delete it?

Comment: If you want to delete the VPC, then you have to delete all its EIPs, instances, NATs, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marcin stated in question comments - I deleted first the Elastic IP, than EC2 instances and NATs, after that the rest was successfully deleted by cloud formation